# jQuery CSS Selector background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've to do the following simple CSS selector using jQuery , but I can't :

```
"#test > *"
```

I've tried in many ways but I just can't do that!

```
$("#jqt > *")
```

or

```
$('*',$("#jqt")).css()
```

the last one seemed to work but I realized that it shoudnt!!

How should I do this simple selection to add a very simple CSS property (`background-image` and `font-family`)????

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `$("#jqt > *")` try `$("#jqt").children()`

Answer (score 0):

This works, if you're wanting to select immediate children:

```
$("#jqt > *").css({ 'background-image' : 'url(...)', 'font-family' : 'arial'})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/tG4jf/)

Comment: This selects more than immediate children.  You're selecting all subelements.

Comment: `$("#jqt > *")` doesn't select "subchildren", `$('*', "#jqt")` does. Now that you edited your answer it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to apply css only on the "direct children" of `#jqt`.

Here is a trick to avoid your style from being applied to the sub child elements:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jqt">
    <a>link</a>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <div>div</div>
    <div class="no_inherit">
        <a>sub link</a>
        <p>sub paragraph</p>
        <div>sub div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mystyle {
    background-image: url(img.png);
    font-family: "courier";
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#jqt').children().not(".no_inherit").addClass('mystyle');
```

If you remove `not(".no_inherit")`, the CSS is applied to the elements in the elements in  `#jqt > div`, so all elements are styled.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/7AM5Z/1/